# Map reduce to compute SVD (Singular value decomposition)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to parallelize SVD computing, using for example Hadoop's MAP REDUCE?
Could you provide a simple example of it??

Comment: Do you specifically need a Hadoop method or any way that works in parallel?  Also, do you need the full SVD or a truncated version?

Comment: Only a simple example to begin, and to know how to use hadoop o compute matrix stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can check Mahout Distributed Lanczos SVD implementation